# How to Compare Elements in itertools.combinations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to compare the elements in two `series`.

```
0    1
1    3
2    4
3    2
4    4
Name: s1, dtype: int32
0    3
1    3
2    0
3    5
4    1
Name: s2, dtype: int64
```

In order to compare the `series` easily, I used `itertools.combinations` :

```
x = combinations(s1, 2)
y = combinations(s2, 2)
```

and the result *x* :

```
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(1, 2)
(1, 4)
(3, 4)
(3, 2)
(3, 4)
(4, 2)
(4, 4)
(2, 4)
```

*y* :

```
(3, 3)
(3, 0)
(3, 5)
(3, 1)
(3, 0)
(3, 5)
(3, 1)
(0, 5)
(0, 1)
(5, 1)
```

The method of the comparison is partly similar to Kendall's tau distance. The pairs in *x* `(x1, x2)`, and the pairs in *y* `(y1, y2)`. If `x1 > x2` and `y1 > y2`, or `x1 < x2` and `y1 < y2`, then `score = score+1`; otherwise, `score = score`. But by far, I still can't figure a way compare the elements inside the pairs.

---

Me getting `m1`, `m2`, and `m1|m2` :

m1 :

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

m2 :

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

m1|m2 :

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

I got the same result as yours. I have no idea why it adds up so many time.

---

Both m1 and m2 contains all false values from default. And it surely does, and the currently result is ideally correct. But I want the `score` to add 1 everytime `(m1 | m2) == true`.

```
score
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

The ideal result for score like the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `DataFrame` from output and then modify data by conditions:

```
#changed data for better sample
s1 = pd.Series([1,3,4,2,4])
s2 = pd.Series([3,4,0,5,8])

x = combinations(s1, 2)
y = combinations(s2, 2)

dfx = pd.DataFrame(list(x)).rename(columns=lambda x: x+1).add_prefix('x')
dfy = pd.DataFrame(list(y)).rename(columns=lambda x: x+1).add_prefix('y')
df = pd.concat([dfx, dfy], axis=1)

m1 = (df.x1 > df.x2) & (df.y1 > df.y2)
m2 = (df.x1 < df.x2) & (df.y1 < df.y2)
m = m1 | m2

print (m)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
9     True
dtype: bool
```

---

```
df['score'] = np.where(m, m.cumsum(), 0)
print (df)
   x1  x2  y1  y2  score
0   1   3   3   4      1
1   1   4   3   0      0
2   1   2   3   5      2
3   1   4   3   8      3
4   3   4   4   0      0
5   3   2   4   5      0
6   3   4   4   8      4
7   4   2   0   5      0
8   4   4   0   8      0
9   2   4   5   8      5
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the result. For the row[1] `1 4 3 0`, `1 < 4, 3 > 0`, it shouldn't add score, and other rows have the same problem.

Comment: @JerryChen - So conditions in your question are wrong? `If x1 > x2 and y1 > y2, or x1 < x2 and y1 < y2, then score = score+1; otherwise, score = score.` ?

Comment: @JerryChen - Onkly change `<` and `>` like you need.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. But I can't see anything wrong with m1 and m2. I think m1 and m2 correspond what I need, but the result isn't.

Comment: @JerryChen - It is weird, because if wrong `>` or `<` it working correcty? can you explain more?

Comment: I need `score` to add 1 when `(x1 > x2) & (y1 > y2)` or when `(x1 < x2) & (y1 < y2)`. In the row[1] `1 < 4, 3 > 0`, which doesn't correspond my conditions, adds 1. In row[2] it corresponds the condition `(x1 < x2) & (y1 < y2)`, but it adds 2.

Comment: @JerryChen - I get for `row 1` False (`1 < 4, 3 < 0`) or (`1 > 4, 3 > 0`), added output from `masks` to answer. Can you check it?

Comment: Edited in the main question. I think there's nothing wrong with m1, m2 outputs. What do you mean added output from masks?

Comment: @JerryChen - hmmm, maybe main problem is I dont understand expected output. Can you add it to question? What is in column `df['score']` before apply this solution?

Comment: Edited above. The output is all correct, except for `score`. BTW, thank you for your patience, you really help me a lot.

Comment: @JerryChen - so need change `df['score'] = range(10)` to `df['score'] = 0` ?

Comment: @JerryChen - Changed sample data for multiple `True`s in mask `m`, can you check my solution now?

Comment: It's correct! Learned so much from you , you really saved my day!